# How to limit the selection of checkboxes in VB.NET 2010

Tags: vb.net

[image]

I want the user to be able to check only 5 checkboxes then if they attempt to check more than 5 either the other unchecked boxes will be disabled or a message box will pop up saying "You can only select 5 seats". Then if the user unchecks 1 box the disabled check boxes will be enabled again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is have a variable with a count of the checkboxes checked:

```
Private cbChecked As Integer = 0
```

Then, create a handler for all the Checkboxes `CheckedChanged` event, something like this:

```
Private Sub CheckBoxes_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) 
                     Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged, CheckBox2.CheckedChanged ...
Dim cb As CheckBox = TryCast(sender, CheckBox)
If cb.Checked Then
    cbChecked += 1
Else
    cbChecked -= 1
End If
If cbChecked = 5 Then
    For Each cbx As CheckBox In Me.Controls.OfType(Of CheckBox)
        If Not cbx.Checked Then
            cbx.Enabled = False
        End If
    Next
Else
    For Each cbx As CheckBox In Me.Controls.OfType(Of CheckBox)
        cbx.Enabled = True
    Next

End If

End Sub
```

This can give you an idea of what to do.

Comment: I'll try. Thanks for the tip. I'll tell you if I did it.